# php выдаёт ошибку 500 при получение класа

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents('https://time100.ru/online',false,$context);
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$classname="time";
$time = $dom->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
echo $time->nodeValue;
?>
```

Выдаёт HTTP ERROR 500

PHP версии 7.1

Comment: <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n4o7vo

Comment: теперь у вас есть все необходимые данные, чтобы начать исправлять свои ошибки

Comment: удалил 9 линию,ошибка

Comment: я удалил 9 и 12 линию и потом 11 линию,но теперь ничего не выдаёт. Пустой экран.

Comment: @ Dizzy221 что делать?

Comment: У `$dom` нет метода `query`. Курите документацию